# Using C library with React Native

Tags: android, c, react-native, android-ndk, buck

I do not have a background in Android Application Development but have taken a task where I need to use the C library  (game engine written in C) with the android application. I have some background in NodeJS and thus have decided to use `React Native` to build this app which will communicate with the C library. I need some inputs just because I could not find much on Web. A friend recommended me using `Buck` for this. I do not really know if this would be helpful but have come across [some steps to build android app using buck](https://github.com/fbsamples/bucksamples/tree/master/cross-platform-scale-2015-demo) but it just did not work for me.

So I had done the following steps:

```
mkdir buck-project
cd buck-project
buck project buck-project --ide intellij
cd ../ && buck installbuck-project
```

But that does not work and gives an error that buck project references non-existent directory. This is all I have done.

I would appreciate any help in here. If I am able to create a small application where I could send the parameters back and forth between the C code and react-native, it will be a very good starting point.

Comment: It is not clear how react-native can be applied to a game that uses an engine written in C. I mean, it is possible to use some C libraries in react-native Android apps, but the game engine may expect some different kind of app.

Comment: @AlexCohn Okay. You could think this in a way that, I need to pass some inputs in exchange of an output. How do I do this?

Comment: I am the co-maintainer of Realm JavaScript, which is an C++ engine used in React Native. Maybe you can draw some inspiration from https://github.com/realm/realm-js/tree/master/react-native/android/src/main/jni.